# RequestFactory ValueProxy class with embedded List of another ValueProxy not visible in response on client

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

I have a requestfactory service request that returns a List<> of RoleProxy.  The RoleProxy contains a List<> of PermissionProxy.  I can see the data coming back from the server.  I can see it in the data that is being parsed by the AutoBean decode.  But the response RoleProxy in  the onSuccess method does not have any data in it's List<>.

Here is the RoleProxy

```
@ProxyForName("com.ihg.atp.schema.crs.revenue.sbrpa.datatypes.v1.RolesType")
public interface RoleProxy extends ValueProxy {
    public int getId();

    public void setId(final int id);

    public String getName();

    public void setName(final String name);

    public List<PermissionProxy> getPermissions();

    public void setPermissions(final List<PermissionProxy> permissions);

}
```

The Permissions Proxy

```
@ProxyForName("com.ihg.atp.schema.crs.revenue.sbrpa.datatypes.v1.PageType")
public interface PermissionProxy extends ValueProxy {
    public String getPageIndex();

    public void setPageIndex(final String pageIndex);

    public String getAccessType();

    public void setAccessType(final String accessType);
}
```

And the calling routine

```
RolesContext ctx = requestFactory.rolesContext();
ctx.getAllRoles().with("permissions").fire(new Receiver<List<RoleProxy>>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(List<RoleProxy> response) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        List<PermissionProxy> perms = response.get(0).getPermissions();
        // Here perms is an empty list instead of the data that was sent
    }
});
```

Does anyone have an idea of what is happening here?  I have done similar things in the past with EntityProxies.

On Edit: Added link to [response body](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2u-woM8S8BAbzh3ZXJOcFI2S1U/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: It might seems silly but: have you checked that `getPermissions` returns a non-empty list when called on the server-side? (BTW, you don't need `with("permissions")` with `ValueProxy`-s).

Comment: That isn't silly Thomas.  But I did check that.  I can see the data when looking at the request in the browser debugger, and when I step through the requestfactory request handler I can see it up to the point the AutoBean decodes the data.   I didn't think I needed the with() clause, but put it there just in case that is what was telling the decode not to give me the data.

Comment: Thomas, should how this is coded work?  From everything I have seen in the docs it seems like it should to me.  Am I missing something?  Is it possible it is a bug that has slipped in?

Comment: It indeed is possible that there's a bug (RF is complex enough that it's littered with small –and not so small– bugs) but I doubt it's the case here (this looks like a very common use-case, and those generally work). Could you add the response payload to your question?

Comment: The response body was quite large, so I stored it on google drive and have provided a link to it.  The objects have a few more data fields than my example which cut out some non important data to illuminate the problem.

Comment: Crap! Looks like a bug when deserializing. That said, try to reduce your payload, it's HUGE!

Comment: I know it's huge. We have some stories to break the data up.  I just have to get the product owners to put those stories in a sprint.  I can probably get this request broken up as part of this story though.  I  will request the enclosed list as a separate call.